# Change order of products out of stock on Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, code-snippets, stock

I was using the code below to order the products by stock.
But I don't know why it stops working, I can't remember if it was related with 8.4.0 update or Elementor maybe, but I'm using normal archieve catalog for it, but it was working two weeks ago as I remember.
Someone has a clue about it?
I did not wish to roll back all the plugins, this will be my last alternative.
My mistake was to keep auto update on the plugins enable.

```
if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
    add_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_stock_status', 2000);
}

function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
    $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
    $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
    $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
    }
    return $posts_clauses;
}

add_filter('post_class', 'custom_out_of_stock_class');

function custom_out_of_stock_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    if ($product && !$product->is_in_stock()) {
        $classes[] = 'out-of-stock-product';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

I also tried different codes but all old form the web and the result is the same.
No order is done.

Comment: I roll back to 8.3 and the problem seems to continue.
I saw that the class out-of-stock-product is not being added to the products.